# Cannot Edit Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I published two apps and both were pretty similar code. One was a lite version and one was a pro version. Now, when I go into Eclipse, one can be edited and the other doesn't show Android information/has build errors. I go to the properties and one shows it doesnt have Android (the one that wont edit) but when I try to select 4.2.2 it does nothing.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the files are marked read-only on the file system?

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I originally hired a freelancer to make the apps and I'm not extremely Android/Exlipse literate, which is why I'm hear for help!

Comment: You'd do it through the operating system, using Windows Explorer on Windows, a terminal on Linux, etc. In Windows, you can check the properties of the file, as well as the security permissions, to see if you have read-only access. In Linux, you can do an ls -al on the directory, make sure you have 'w' permission to the files.